# How do I fix the Java errors when I'm not using FXML?

Tags: java, javafx

So I've been working on a JavaFX program (quick project for my college class because my college was going to allow me to sit for a certification exam as my course project, but with COVID-19 that went out the window with the college going fully online).  The program complied (using the javac command) with no errors.  However, when I attempt to run (using the java command) the program, I get a list of errors:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[D@74015eb0"
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
        at Main.start(Main.java:37)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:186)
        ... 1 more
Exception running application Main
```

Every other question I've seen asked with these errors involved at least one FXML file, a language I am not familiar with.  My code is below (I structured it based off another version of the same program, but it was C++11 without any other language or external libraries for GUI; and I apologize for the shear size of the code).  How would I resolve the issues?  (In case anybody is wondering: This is my first time in a year since I last used Java, and this is my very first time using JavaFX.)

```
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
    import javafx.event.EventHandler;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
    import javafx.scene.text.Text;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.DataInputStream;
    import java.io.DataOutputStream;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Date;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        String busName = "";
        String busAddress = "";

        final int[] cCI = {1}; //Declared so it can be reassigned a number from within EventHandler.
        cCI[0] = 1; //Will be changed later if assigned radio button is modified later.

        final boolean[] sTax = {false};
        boolean salesTaxAdd = sTax[0];
        final int[] SalesTax = {1};
        SalesTax[0] = 0; //Will be changed later if assigned radio button is modified later.
        //Variables for storing sales tax info.
        final String[] stpString = {"0.00"};
        final double[] salesTaxPercent = {Double.parseDouble(stpString[0]) / 100};
        setTaxPercent(Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(salesTaxPercent)), 2);

        final boolean[] radioCheck = {true}; //initializes value for UDF, UDF will change if R.B. is interacted with.


        businessInfo(busName);
        businessAddress(busAddress);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Final Project - Business Program v2.0 - J.D.K. S.E. 8 Update 241");
        //Defining Grid Pane
        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        gridPane.setMinSize(3,3);

        Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        //Event Handlers
        EventHandler<ActionEvent> transaction = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                try {
                    operatingProcedures(1, busName, busAddress, cCI[0], salesTaxPercent[0], SalesTax[0]);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        EventHandler<ActionEvent> cost = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                try {
                    operatingProcedures(2, busName, busAddress, cCI[0], salesTaxPercent[0], SalesTax[0]);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        EventHandler<ActionEvent> endOfDay = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                try {
                    operatingProcedures(3, busName, busAddress, cCI[0], salesTaxPercent[0], SalesTax[0]);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        EventHandler<ActionEvent> resetName = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                try {
                    businessInfo(busName);
                    businessAddress(busAddress);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        EventHandler<ActionEvent> radioChanged = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                try {
                    if (radioCheck[0] == true) {
                        setRadio(false);
                    }
                    if (radioCheck[0] == false){
                        setRadio(true);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                cCI[0] = 2; //Tells system not to collect customer information.
            }
        };
        EventHandler<ActionEvent> toAddSalesTax = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                try{
                    if (sTax[0] == false) {
                        addTax(true);
                        SalesTax[0] = 1;

                        stpString[0] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your state's sales tax as a decimal (or the percent divided by 100):");
                        setTaxPercent(Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(salesTaxPercent)), 1);
                    }
                    if (sTax[0] == true){
                        addTax(false);
                        SalesTax[0] = 0;
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        //Defining Buttons
        Button revenue = new Button("Conduct Transaction");
        revenue.setOnAction(transaction);

        Button expense = new Button ("Record Expense");
        expense.setOnAction(cost);

        Button eod = new Button ("End of Day (Close)");
        eod.setOnAction(endOfDay);

        Button changeName = new Button("Change Business Name");
        changeName.setOnAction(resetName);

        //Setting for Collecting Customer's address & accompanying boolean to be stored

        setRadio(radioCheck[0]);
        RadioButton collectInfo = new RadioButton("Collect Customer's Address?");
        collectInfo.setSelected(radioCheck[0]);
        collectInfo.setOnAction(radioChanged);

        //Setting for Sales Tax
        addTax(salesTaxAdd);
        RadioButton stateSalesTax = new RadioButton("Add State Sales Tax");
        stateSalesTax.setSelected(sTax[0]);

        //Business Name label
        Text text = new Text(busName);

        //Add widgets to GridPane
        gridPane.add(text, 1, 0);
        gridPane.add(revenue, 0, 1);
        gridPane.add(expense, 1, 1);
        gridPane.add(eod, 2, 1);
        gridPane.add(changeName, 0, 2);
        gridPane.add(collectInfo, 1, 2);
        gridPane.add(stateSalesTax, 2, 2);

        primaryStage.show();
    }


    //Start User-Defined Functions of the Program.
    public static double setTaxPercent (double taxInfo, int saveLoad) throws IOException{
        if (saveLoad == 1){
            //Saving Function;
            try{
                PrintWriter saveInfo = new PrintWriter("taxPercent.dat");
                saveInfo.print(taxInfo);
                saveInfo.close();
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                File file = new File ("taxPercent.dat");
                PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("taxPercent.dat");
                outputFile.print(taxInfo);
                outputFile.close();
            }

        }
        if (saveLoad == 2){
            //Loading Function;
            try{
                FileInputStream load = new FileInputStream("taxPercent.dat");
                taxInfo = load.read();
                load.close();
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                //Prepare File and preload default setting
                File file = new File ("taxPercent.dat");
                PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("taxPercent.dat");
                outputFile.print(0.00);
                outputFile.close();
            }
        }
        return taxInfo;
    }

    public static boolean addTax (boolean tax) throws IOException{
        try{
            FileInputStream ast = new FileInputStream("addSalesTax.dat");
            DataInputStream astBoolean = new DataInputStream(ast);
            tax = astBoolean.readBoolean();
            astBoolean.close();
            ast.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            File file = new File ("addSalesTax.dat");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);
            dos.writeBoolean(tax);
            dos.close();
            fos.close();
        }

        return tax;
    }

    public static boolean setRadio (boolean radio) throws IOException{
        //Loads and Saves state of Radio Button
        try{
            FileInputStream rc = new FileInputStream("radio.dat");
            DataInputStream checkRadio = new DataInputStream(rc);
            radio = checkRadio.readBoolean();
            checkRadio.close();
            rc.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            File file = new File ("radio.dat");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("radio.dat");
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);
            dos.writeBoolean(radio);
            dos.close();
            fos.close();
        }

        return radio;
    }

    public static String businessInfo (String varName) throws IOException {
        //Name will be stored in a Data file vice a Text file
        try {
            FileInputStream in = null;
            //Name
            in = new FileInputStream("Name.dat");
            Scanner read = new Scanner(in);
            varName = read.nextLine();
            read.close();
            in.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            File file = new File("Name.dat");
            varName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your business's name:");
            PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("Name.dat");
            outputFile.print(varName);
            outputFile.close();
        }
        return varName;
    }

    public static String businessAddress (String varAddress) throws IOException{
        String varStreet, varCity, varST, varZIP;
        try{
            FileInputStream address = null;

            //Street Address
            address = new FileInputStream("Street.dat");
            Scanner street = new Scanner(address);
            varStreet = street.nextLine();
            street.close();
            address.close();

            //City
            address = new FileInputStream("City.dat");
            Scanner city = new Scanner(address);
            varCity = city.nextLine();
            city.close();
            address.close();

            //State (ST)
            address = new FileInputStream("State.dat");
            Scanner state = new Scanner(address);
            varST = state.nextLine();
            state.close();
            address.close();

            //Zip w/out 4 code
            address = new FileInputStream("zip.dat");
            Scanner zip = new Scanner(address);
            varZIP = zip.nextLine();
            zip.close();
            address.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            //Street
            File file = new File ("Street.dat");
            varStreet = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your business's street address:");
            PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("Street.dat");
            outputFile.print(varStreet);
            outputFile.close();

            //City
            file = new File ("City.dat");
            varCity = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the city (don't include the state) is your business in?");
            outputFile = new PrintWriter("City.dat");
            outputFile.print(varCity);
            outputFile.close();

            //State
            file = new File ("State.dat");
            varST = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the state your business is located in.");
            outputFile = new PrintWriter("State.dat");
            outputFile.print(varST);
            outputFile.close();

            //ZIP
            file = new File ("zip.dat");
            varZIP = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your ZIP address (4-code not needed).");
            outputFile = new PrintWriter("zip.dat");
            outputFile.print(varZIP);
            outputFile.close();
        }
        varAddress = varStreet + "\n" + varCity + ", " + varST + " " + varZIP;

        return varAddress;
    }

    public static void operatingProcedures(int opSelection, String theName, String theAddress, int ica, double theTax, int useTax) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int x = 1; //Used for Revenue arrays
        int y = 1; //Used for Expense arrays
        String[] revenueName = new String [x];
        double[] revenueValue = new double [x];
        String[] expenseName = new String [y];
        double[] expenseValue = new double [y];
        double totalRevenue = 0; //Used in EOD Procedures
        double totalExpense = 0; //Used in EOD Procedures
        double netIncome; //Used in EOD Procedures; will state a net gain or net loss for the day.
        if (opSelection == 1){
            int numItems;
            //Revenue Reporting
            if (ica == 1){
                //This procedure collects customer information
                String customerName, customerStreet, customerCity, customerST;
                int customerZIP;
                customerName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the customer's name:");
                customerStreet = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the customer's street address; without city, state, or zip code:");
                customerCity = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the customer's city:");
                customerST = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the customer's abbreviated (i.e \"FL\" for \"Florida\": ");
                customerZIP = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the customer's ZIP code:"));

                numItems = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many items are sold in this transaction?"));

                //Start Billing Process
                String[] itemName = new String [numItems]; //Holds items' respective names
                double[] itemPrice = new double [numItems]; //Holds items' respective prices
                double runningTotal = 0.0;

                for (int a = 0; a < numItems; a++){
                    itemName[a] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the item's name:");
                    itemPrice[a] = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter " + itemName[a] + "'s price:"));
                    runningTotal += itemPrice[a];
                }

                //File naming
                Date dateSaleWithName = new Date();
                String dateOnReceipt = String.format("ddMMyyyy", dateSaleWithName);

                String receiptName = customerName + dateOnReceipt;

                File file = new File(receiptName); //For output
                PrintWriter sale = new PrintWriter(file);

                sale.print(theName + "\n" + theAddress + "\n\n");
                sale.print(customerName + "\n" + customerStreet + "\n" + customerCity + ", " + customerST + " " + customerZIP);
                sale.print("\n\nItem name\t\tItem Price\n");
                for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++){
                    sale.print(itemName[i] + "\t\t" + itemPrice[i] + "\n");
                }
                if (useTax == 1){
                    double taxAmount = runningTotal * theTax;
                    sale.print("\nSales Tax\t\t" + runningTotal + "\n");

                    double trueTotal = runningTotal + taxAmount;
                    sale.print("Total\t\t" + trueTotal);

                    //Recording Tax expense
                    expenseName[y-1] = "Sales Tax - " + receiptName;
                    expenseValue[y-1] = taxAmount;
                    y++;
                }
                else{
                    sale.print("Total\t\t" + runningTotal);
                }

                //Recording in System
                revenueName[x-1] = receiptName;
                revenueValue[x-1] = runningTotal;
            }
            else{
                //This procedure does NOT collect customer information.
                numItems = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many items are sold in this transaction?"));

                //Start Billing Process
                String[] itemName = new String [numItems]; //Holds items' respective names
                double[] itemPrice = new double [numItems]; //Holds items' respective prices
                double runningTotal = 0.0;

                for (int a = 0; a < numItems; a++){
                    itemName[a] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the item's name:");
                    itemPrice[a] = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter " + itemName[a] + "'s price:"));
                    runningTotal += itemPrice[a];
                }

                //File naming
                Date dateSaleWithoutName = new Date();
                String dateOnReceipt = String.format("ddMMyyyy HH:mm:ss", dateSaleWithoutName);

                String receiptName =  dateOnReceipt;

                File file = new File(receiptName); //For output
                PrintWriter sale = new PrintWriter(file);

                sale.print(theName + "\n" + theAddress + "\n\n");
                sale.print("\n\nItem name\t\tItem Price\n");
                for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++){
                    sale.print(itemName[i] + "\t\t" + itemPrice[i] + "\n");
                }
                if (useTax == 1){
                    double taxAmount = runningTotal * theTax;
                    sale.print("\nSales Tax\t\t" + runningTotal + "\n");

                    double trueTotal = runningTotal + taxAmount;
                    sale.print("Total\t\t" + trueTotal);

                    //Recording Tax expense
                    expenseName[y-1] = "Sales Tax - " + receiptName;
                    expenseValue[y-1] = taxAmount;
                    y++;
                }
                else{
                    sale.print("Total\t\t" + runningTotal);
                }

                //Recording in System
                revenueName[x-1] = receiptName;
                revenueValue[x-1] = runningTotal;
            }
            x++;
        }
        else if (opSelection == 2){
            //Expense Reporting
            expenseName[y - 1] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the name for incurred Expense:");
            expenseValue[y - 1] = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the value for the incurred Expense:"));
            y += 1;
        }
        else {
            //End-of-Day(EOD) Procedures
            Date date = new Date();
            String dateForFile = String.format("MM-dd-yyyy", date);
            File file = new File (dateForFile);
            PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(dateForFile);
            outputFile.print(theName + "\n");
            outputFile.print("\n" + dateForFile + "\n");

            //Revenue Recording Procedure
            outputFile.print("Revenue Name\t\tRevenue Value\n");
            for (int r = 0; r < x; r++){
                outputFile.print(revenueName[r] + "t\\t" + revenueValue[r] + "\n");
                totalRevenue += revenueValue[r];
            }
            outputFile.print("Total Revenue:\t\t" + totalRevenue + "\n\n");

            //Expense Recording Procedure
            outputFile.print("Expense Name\t\tExpense Value\n");
            for (int e = 0; e < y; e++){
                outputFile.print(expenseName[e] + "\t\t" + expenseValue[e] + "\n");
                totalExpense += expenseValue[e];
            }
            outputFile.print("Total Expense:\t\t" + totalExpense + "\n\n\n");

            //Record Document Footer
            outputFile.print("\tTotal Revenue:\t" + totalRevenue + "\n");
            outputFile.print("\tTotal Expenses:\t" + totalExpense + "\n");
            netIncome = totalRevenue - totalExpense;
            if (netIncome > 0){
                outputFile.print("\tToday's Net Gain\t" + netIncome);
            }
            else if (netIncome < 0){
                outputFile.print("\tToday's Net Loss\t" + netIncome);
            }
            else{
                //This section should never execute, but it is here on the off chance that it needs to.
                outputFile.print("\tToday's Yield:\t" + netIncome);
            }

            return;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: This line is the problem: `setTaxPercent(Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(salesTaxPercent)), 2);`
You're converting a double array to a string (with its `toString()` method, which pretty much is useless) and then trying to parse it as a double.

Comment: Thank you. That answer actually pointed me in the right direction and my project works like a charm.

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788 to learn how to read the error messages and figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is recommended to keep questions as short and concise as possible by removing any information that is not essential to understand the problem.

Comment: Indeed you could have easily removed JavaFX from the equation and narrowed down the issue to the 3 lines ending at the line mentioned by xehpuk